# Integration limits condition

Tags: calculus

When we perform integration, do we need the function to be defined at the interval limits where it's being considered? For example integral of $x^2\ dx$ from $1$ to $4$, is it necessary that we need $f(1), f(4)$ to be defined? Or continuous/differentiable there? Is the only condition being that integral should be properly defined in $(1,4)$ and not $[1,4]$?

Comment: Have you heard of the improper integrals?

Comment: I think that Riemann integrability definition does require continuity on the closed interval. However, one of the [basic theorems of Lebesgue integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Basic_theorems_of_the_Lebesgue_integral) is that if two functions are equal [almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) then their integrals are equal. So (in the Lebesgue sense) since the endpoints are a null set, removing them doesn't change the integral.

Comment: Okay thanks @RobertLee

Comment: Since no one else has seen fit to offer this reaction, I will.  +1 to your question, which I regard as an outstanding question for a Math student new to Real Analysis to ask.

Comment: Thank you @user2661923